# app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); ReferenceError: path is not defined what is issue?

Tags: node.js, express

Console in NodeJS command prompt

```
Error Message for app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
"ReferenceError: path is not defined"
```

I use express version 3.3.5.

What is the problem?

Comment: var path = require('path'); can you add this and check

Answer (score 12):

You need to require path npm module like this

```
const path = require('path');
```

As path is a part of  [nodejs core module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html), it doesn't need to be listed explicitly

Comment: `path` is a core module, it doesn't need to be listed explicitly.

Comment: `path` is a core module, doesn't need to be installed or declared in `package.json`

Comment: Thanks Ingo and perostek, I have corrected my answer

Answer (score 5):

You need to require `path` module

```
const path = require('path')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the issue

```
var path = require('path');
```

Answer (score 0):

for ESM

```js
import path from "path"
```

Answer (score -2):

To resolve this issue, you might want to

1. explicitly import the path module:

   ```
    var path = require('path');
   ```
2. Then, you can use var path like:

   ```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../')));
   ```

Comment: `path` is a core module, doesn't need to be installed or declared in `package.json`